# HDMI + DisplayPort, both monitors detected, DP has no signal

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, intel-nuc

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 on an Intel NUC10i7FNH.

I connected two identical monitors, one on the HDMI port, a second with DP-HDMI adapter on the DisplayPort (Thunderbolt).
Sometimes this works as expected, but more often than not, the monitor connected to the DP receives no signal. Reboot, and it may or may not work the next time.
Both monitors have picture (BIOS, Intel NUC logo), until the Ubuntu logon screen appears, then the one on DP (usually) goes dark.

Even when the DP has no signal, both monitors *are* detected correctly. Both appear as 'Samsung Electric Company 24"' in GUI display settings. I can move the mouse into the second monitor area, there is a delay before it appears again moving it back out depending on how far I moved it in, so the OS thinks it *is* using it.

But xrandr output has it wrong. It lists both monitors, but both connected to DP, and it shows HDMI as disconnected. This while the one on HDMI is working, it is the DP one that has no signal. I am deleting the lines for inactive resolutions below to save space.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
[... other res snipped ...]
DP-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
[... other res snipped ...]
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This remains the same whether the second monitor has signal or not.
I also tried making the other monitor primary, doesn change anything.

[Edit]
Those times that it works, it remains OK until shutdown as long as the system doesn't blank the monitors (screensaver). If it does, most of the time only the first monitor comes back on.

Success rate (both monitors having signal after boot) is 1 time in 5, at best.

Comment: Is the DP⇢HDMI adapter an active or passive unit? Generally I have found the passive ones to be hit and miss 

Comment: Thanks, Matigo. Actually it was an active one AFAIK, and replacing it by a passive one fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just got fixed. The DisplayPort -> HDMI adapter was a Dell DA300 combo (HDMI + displayPort + ethernet + USB3 + C pass-through) I had from my laptop.

Replacing it by a simple/cheap passive C type DisplayPort -> HDMI adapter fixed it.

Comment: And of course, that fix arrived an hour and a half after posting a question, when 3 days of searching and experimenting before didn't solve anything. I just bought a cheap adapter at Carrefour, our local equivalent of Tesco and Walmart, and tried it :)